# Searching between values in python dict or list

Tags: python

I'm looking for a performant way to lookup for value in a dict or list.
In a database the primary key would be Key, DateFrom, DateTo and I'm looking to get the Value item.
Dates are not overlapping.

The search query is in SQL would be:

```
select Value from MyStruct where Key = @MyKey and DateFrom <= @MyDate and DateTo >= @Mydate
```

How can I achieve this in any pure python structure fast?
I'm actually loading huge amount of data from an XML file and I would like to avoid roundtrips to the database just to get the value (translate Key into Value).
In the original XML file @MyKey and @MyDate are given and I have to find out the corresponding Value

Comment: List comprehension is what you want, almost the same as your sql.

Comment: Well, as far as I know a dict has EXACTLY one entry per key. And here I have several (one for each DateFrom/DateTo pairs)

Comment: One entry can contain all these info. You need to provide your Python data as code, not description or some sql code.

Comment: This is my point. I do not know hot to structure my data. Normally if I would look for exact values my dict would look like mydict[Key, DateFrom, DateTo] = Value. But this is not my case as I'm not looking for exact match of dates but a "between" match. I can express it in SQL but not in python. That's why I've provided the SQL code. Just for comprehension

Comment: I think you need to consider another structure for your data. Dictionaries and lists are good, but `pandas` is usually more efficient as it vectorises what is normally "loopy" functionality.

Comment: If it really is a huge amount of data, then a database may in fact be the best way to go. You should be able to rely on the DBMS to cache the data sensibly in memory and combine information from the indexes on the date fields to get efficiently to the row you want.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option you can load your data into pandas dataframe, it's quick for multiple selections and dates operations, the below example is for selecting rows between dates:

```
in_range_df = df[df["date"].isin(pd.date_range("2018-01-15", "2018-01-20"))]
```